# validation in django templates

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have a django template in which I wanna show the user only if it's name is `emp` for which I am using the following code:

HTML

```
{% if warehouse.warehouse.owner == emp %}
<td class="align-middle">{{ warehouse.warehouse.owner }}</td>
{% endif %}
```

It's not working but when I use this without the if condition it shows `emp` in the template. How do I equate both of them in the template ?

Comment: Why aren't you using [Django's Form Validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/) ??

Comment: isn't emp a string? `{% if warehouse.warehouse.owner == "emp" %}`

Comment: @Radico I tried this, it doesn't work.. I tried the id(pk) of owner as well i.e `{% if warehouse.warehouse.owner == 1 %}`

Comment: @RahulSharma can you please show me the owner model? I believe you need to do so `{% if warehouse.warehouse.owner.id == 1 %}` or `{% if warehouse.warehouse.owner.name == "emp" %}`

Comment: @Radico owner is a ForeignKey field with a model `Employee` which is a Foreignkey with `User` model

Comment: @RahulSharma Add your Db models in your question.

Comment: Did you try this ?
{% if warehouse.warehouse.owner.username == "emp" %},
'emp' is supposed to be username